# How to get MediaPlayerElement's seeking start event in uwp?

Tags: uwp, media-player, mediaplayerelement

`MediaPlayerElement` has an event called `SeekCompleted`, but does not have a `SeekStarted` event.
This is annoying when I click the slider when the network is bad, it seems like the frame is stopped, and `MediaPlayerElement` returns "PlaybackState: Playing", but actually it's not.

In this [video](https://youtu.be/DV19f5UqqTI), my network is not good, and from 00:00:06 to 00:00:19, the video frame is stopped and returns "PlaybackState: Playing". this duration depends on the network.
Until 00:00:19, it returns "PlaybackState: Buffering".

So how can I set a fake buffering from 00:00:06 to 00:00:19, cause this period to the end-user, itis not playing. Thx.

[image]

Comment: I am not experienced with the `MediaPlayerElement` behavior, but any chance `BufferingProgressChanged` could be used?

Comment: `BufferingProgressChanged` only fired at the beginning of the play, I just test it. But the official doc says "Occurs when the buffering progress for the MediaPlaybackSession changes."

Comment: Could you please tell me if you want an event handler to be triggered when you reset playback progress of a video?

Comment: Reset progress event? No.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, from 00:00:06 to 00:00:19 in the video, I can use a `Timer`, which ticks 1 second, to detect the `PlaybackSession.Position`.

If the position is the same as the last second, then show a fake buffering.

But we have to consider video pause, so we can use like this.

```
if(video.state != pause)
{
   if(newPosition == oldPosition)
      ShowBuffer();
}
```